# How to get proxy setting from chromedriver in java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a piece of code that automatically gets the proxy when it creates the chromedriver, and then configures the proxy into the chromedriver. Is there a way to get this proxy from the chromedriver object?

Here is my code:

```
public void getProxyFromDriver() {
    ChromeDriver driver = getDriver();
    //get the proxy from driver; 
    //ip, port, proxyType should be the same as the argument added when create the driver.
    MyProxy proxy;
}

private ChromeDriver getDriver() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromeDriverPath");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    MyProxy proxy = getMyProxy(); //auto get proxy
    options.addArguments("--proxy-server=" + proxy.type + "://" + proxy.ip + ":" + proxy.port);
    return new ChromeDriver(options);
}

private MyProxy getMyProxy() {
    //Here is just an example, it is actually obtained randomly from the database.
    MyProxy myProxy = new MyProxy();
    myProxy.ip = "192.168.2.199";
    myProxy.port = 1090;
    myProxy.type = "SOCKS";
    return myProxy;
}

private class MyProxy {
    private String ip;
    private int port;
    private String type;
}
```

If I can't get the proxy directly, is there any good advice besides adding the proxy as a parameter?

UPDATE:

I am trying to get the proxy through the following code:

```
Proxy proxy = (Proxy) driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("proxy");
```

But I can't get the proxy ip(or host) and port and proxyType from the returned `proxy` object.

Answer (score 0):

`proxy` is one of normal [Selenium Desired Capabilities](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Capabilities+In+Selenium+Tests)

[image]

So you can access it by calling [driver.getCapabilities()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#getCapabilities--) function like:

```
Proxy proxy = (Proxy) driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("proxy");
```

Remember that the function will return an instance of [`org.openqa.selenium.Proxy`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Proxy.html) so you will need to either use the above class or make sure that your `MyProxy` class is compatible with the Selenium's one.

Comment: I updated my question and tried your suggestion, but it was not what I wanted. Any other suggestions?